Booking special meal in plane and ticket verification
I just booked a ticket specifically China Southern Airlines and after paying for the ticket they give the option to book a meal.
I’m wondering if I can book a meal now when my flight is in November, or has to be when it’s close.
And also since this is my first time booking our tickets myself I want to know how to verify it just to calm myself from worrying if I booked in the legit website. Btw I booked from Skyscanner’s link directly to China Southern Airlines

As far as airline food goes I would consider China Southern to be pretty good but if you are really worried about a special meal on the flight (maybe because of allergies) you can also just play it safe and bring your own food. Airlines will try to accomodate special requests but if this causes you a lot of stress, you own food may be less hassle.

I wouldn't worry about booking a special meal too far in advance. Once it's registered in their system, it's handled very routinely. It can be a problem booking a special meal too shortly before the flight, but a couple of days is usually fine. The biggest risk is if your flight gets changed with short notice for some reason. Then you're likely to lose your meal.

What quarague says- If I was worried, I would have a backup plan, pack adequate snacks or whatever, just in case, no matter how solid the special meal booking looks. Airlines and their suppliers are not infallible. You'll seldom catch the Chinese travelling without vast quantities of food and snacks packed away in reserve.

Make an account with China Southern Airlines (if you haven't already). Add your booking to your account (if that's not there already). The page should look like this https://oversea.csair.com/tka/us/en/my/order/ .
Then you should be able to manage your booking directly on their website. That typically includes ordering or selecting meals, selecting seats, change dates (which can be expensive), add luggage, etc.

I want to know how to verify it just to calm myself from worrying if I booked in the legit website.

You only need to worry if you put your name and your booking code into Southern China's website and they come back with a message "booking not found".

Btw I booked from skyscanner’s link directly to china southern airlines

You are fine then. Skyscanner is a very reputable website and booking directly on the airline's website is the best way of doing that.
Update from the comment

The booking reference I got starts with “Go” and ends with 707.

The booking reference or PNR (Passenger Name Record) is a six digit code made from letters and/or numbers.

Could it be possible that it’s too early to check it since only been few hours and may not be reflected yet?

Not really. The booking reference gets issues right away, so you should be able to see it in your account. It can take up to 24 hours for the ticket to be issued (which is an paper work thing), so there is no harm in trying again tomorrow.

Email came from czmp@csair.com is this the legit one?

Yes. That's legit. Your booking is fine.

I do have an account which I used for booking instead of booking without logging in. But upon checking booking is not found or maybe I typed it wrong? The booking reference I got starts with “Go” and ends with 707. Could it be possible that it’s too early to check it since only been few hours and may not be reflected yet? Although I received an email for itinerary to print should I still be worried? Email came from czmp@csair.com is this the legit one?

Are you sure you're looking in the right place for the booking reference? It's a six-character string like "ABCDEF", perhaps with a number or two mixed in.

@RoshanneAyson: I added answers to your comment to my answer

@RoshanneAyson. If you can't find the booking reference you can post an image of this email here and we can help you find it. Before you do this, please make sure you block out all personal details (name, address, birth date, etc)

When I checked using reference number in “my order” column, they couldn’t find it. However, upon exploring their website I was able to find the option for special meal and they were able to identify my flight through my ticket number and airline code. I was able to book special meal and also got relief when it is confirmed that the email address who sent me the itinerary is the legit csair. Thank you so much for the helps guys.
